# Escape tab character PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, escaping, plpgsql

I have got a varchar field and I am migrating this field to a JSON type field. Some of the data has got tabulator, and when trying to insert to the new JSON field it tells me this error: DETAIL:  Character with value 0x09 must be escaped.

I am trying to escape and delete tabulator characters like this but no succes:

```
v_text:=REPLACE(text, '\x09', '');
```

or

```
 v_text:=REPLACE(text, '0x09', '');
```

How can I delete all tabulator characters from a text?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using regular expressions:

```
select regexp_replace(text, '\t', '', 'g');
```

Comment: It is still telling me: DETAIL:  Character with value 0x09 must be escaped.

Comment: @Za7pi Can you provide text value you are trying to manipulate (or at least problematic part of it) ?

Comment: I am going to put you single quote at the beggining and at finish: 'xxxx xxxx x   x  x   '

Comment: Last try, the last a is not in the text: 'xxxx xxxx x   x  x   a'

Comment: If I edit this text here I can see the space or the tab, but you cannot see it

Comment: You can put it into sqlfiddle and post a link here.

Comment: Ok. I am going to try. But by the way. I have got the text in c# and the result is this: xxx x x x xxx\t\t

Comment: @RadekPostołowicz +1 for letting me know that this _Character with value 0x09_ is `\t`!

Comment: Adding documentation link for further reference: [PostgreSQL - String Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-string.html).

Comment: Excellent, still works like a dream, thank you!

Comment: @Za7pi, you mentioned that you got the text in C#. I had the same problem of yours today and I managed to find the solution by escaping the text using regex before sending it to Postgres.  I used this "\\|\t|\\t|\\r|\\n" both on postgresl and C# regexes, in order to prevent that error.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the tabulator in the `replace` as it is (SO formatting replaces tabs with whitespace so just insert tab to where it says `[tab]`):

```
SELECT replace('"a[tab]"', '[tab]', '')::json;
```

Comment: It is not working. I am doing this: v_text:=REPLACE(text, '[tab]', ''); where text is a varchar field

Comment: @Za7pi Cannot reproduce your error. `v json:=REPLACE('"a "'::varchar, ' ', '');` works for me.

Comment: Still error: DETAIL: Character with value 0x09 must be escaped